# How to change the naming structure to a CSV in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, export-to-csv

I am trying to change the name that is printed out on a CSV file that I am creating from an SQL Query. I would like the file name to look like this yyyyddmm_"name". With the year day month capturing the corresponding date on the day of its creation. At the moment I am using pandas and datetime, this is not giving me the correct name structure. Can you sugest an alternative. Thank you for your help with this matter. Cheers.

df.to_csv(r datetime.now()"Name Name" + ".csv", index=False)

Comment: Look at `strftime` in Python's `datetime` module.   - https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import time
file_name = time.strftime("%Y%m%d"+"_Name")
print(file_name)
```

for your case

```
import time
file_name = time.strftime("%Y%m%d"+"_Name")
save_to_path = r'C:\Users\MyPC\Desktop' #this is where your .csv file will be saved
df.to_csv(save_to_path+"\\"+file_name+ ".csv", index=False)
```

Comment: I got this error when I run the above code. descriptor 'strftime' for 'datetime.time' objects doesn't apply to a 'str' object

Comment: Never mind that was my fault I still had listed from datetime. Thank you so much for your help.